# Name for the text within a diary entry

Tags: word-choice

A little background; am writing a pain diary web-api; I am trying to find the best way to describe the main body of text within a diary entry, or is the main body itself the entry?

Assuming 'entry' is the correct word to describe a set of information that pertains to a point in time. Each 'entry' contains:

- Date
- Time
- Pain level
- Medication taken
- ?Description/text/entry?

This last field will be an overall description of how you are feeling, what hurts, the type of pain for each area, etc. What would be the correct name for this field?

Thanks,

Brett

*Note* this isn't about naming a variable, the variable name itself is irrelevant. But rather how to present the concept to a user, or describe the field for help text.

Comment: *Text* is perfectly fine and self-explanatory. *Entry* will work for native speakers, but won't work for all non-native ones. *Description* is too specific, it makes it sound like you are expected to describe the pain but not leave any other *comments* or *notes*. Whether that's desirable, or quite the opposite, will depend on the nature of the app and its target audience.

Comment: They are fair points - i think text sounds a bit too generic in this case. I would say 'notes' best describes what i am trying to encapsulate. May be the case that description of pain and notes should be split out. Though that is a UX question i guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was involved in testing similar functionality apps, in very similar way we use the word "comment" or "notes" which look normal for a user to enter all that he or she is experiencing: description of feelings etc

Comment: Thanks - 'notes' comes pretty close to what i am trying to describe. I will accept this answer if nothing better comes along.